# How can I get an entry of message.properties as a String in backing bean?

Tags: jsf

I need to get `message.properties`'s message as a `String` in backing bean.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is definied as a `message-bundle` of the `application` in `faces-config.xml` like follows

```
<application>
    <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>
</application>
```

then you can get its name by [`Application#getMessageBundle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getMessageBundle%28%29)

```
String messageBundleName = facesContext.getApplication().getMessageBundle();
```

This way you can get its [`ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) instance as follows:

```
ResourceBundle messageBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(messageBundleName);
```

Finally you can get a message property by key as follows:

```
String value = messageBundle.getString("property.key");
```