# Add error message for <f:validateLength> tag customised for a field

Tags: jsf, validation, jsf-2

I have many fields on witch I have to validate length. It's not a problem with `<f:validateLength>` tag. I can also add custom message for this validator.

The problem is the message should be customised for each field. E.g. `firstname` field should have messages "First name too short" or "First name too long", `surname` should have "Surname too short" or "Surname too long" etc. How to achieve that in JSF2.0?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `label` attribute.

```
<h:inputText label="First name">
```

The `{1}` in the message template will be substituted with this.

```
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MAXIMUM: {1} too long.     
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM: {1} too short.
```

Comment: What if I need more customisation? E.g. "First name too short", but "Please provide longer password" Is it possible with JSF? Or maybe with JSR303 Bean Validation. There I can specify message for each field, but I can't specify separate message for value too short and value too long.

Comment: If you want different messages, you've to supply your own custom `LengthValidator` and pass the necessary conditions as `<f:attribute>`. It's available by `UIComponent#getAttributes()` inside `validate()` method. The message bundle base name as you've definied in `faces-config.xml` is by the way available by `Application#getMessageBundle()` with which you can get the message bundle by `ResourceBundle#getBundle()` inside the validator. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138271/jsf-how-can-i-get-the-msg-from-message-property-as-a-string-in-java-code/3140182#3140182).